# Restoring pg_dump hangs

Tags: postgresql, backup, windows, restore

**Aim:** backup a database and restore it in database2

**pg_dump**

A PG Dump has been created by issuing the following command:

`c:\Temp>pg_dump -U postgres postgres > backupTest2.sql`

Opening `backupTest2.sql` shows SQL statements.

**restore pg_dump**

However, once the backup would like to be restored in another database nothing seems to happen (number of tables in database2 remains 0, command hangs).

```
c:\Temp>psql -U postgres -d utrechtTest > backupTest2.sql

^C
```

Comment: The syntax of your restore command is incorrect. Change the direction of the redirect "arrow" (ie `<` instead of `>`) or use the `-f` option of `psql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
psql -U postgres -d utrechtTest > backupTest2.sql
```

runs `psql` and writes its stdout *to* `backupTest2.sql`, which will be overwritten.

You meant:

```
psql -U postgres -d utrechtTest < backupTest2.sql
```

which is better written as:

```
psql -U postgres -d utrechtTest -f backupTest2.sql
```

because if you use `-f` then `psql` can show line numbers.